# bootstrap DatePicker can't display on swedish

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using this DatePicker from bootstrap https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

But I want my months / dates in sweden so I went into the Javascript and I did change the following line: `language: 'en',`too `language: 'sv',`

but than my DatePicker looks like this:

[image]

DatePicker settings:

```
    var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
    autoclose: true,
    beforeShowDay: $.noop,
    beforeShowMonth: $.noop,
    calendarWeeks: false,
    clearBtn: false,
    toggleActive: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
    datesDisabled: [],
    endDate: Infinity,
    forceParse: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    keyboardNavigation: true,
    language: 'sv',
    minViewMode: 0,
    multidate: false,
    multidateSeparator: ',',
    orientation: "auto",
    rtl: false,
    startDate: -Infinity,
    startView: 0,
    todayBtn: false,
    todayHighlight: false,
    weekStart: 1,
    disableTouchKeyboard: false,
    enableOnReadonly: true,
    container: 'body'
};
```

My DatePicker(s) in my View:

```
    $(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#fromDate').datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            firstDay: 1,
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                $('#EndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(dateText));
            }
        });

        $('#toDate').datepicker({
            showButtonPanel: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            firstDay: 1,
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                $('#EndDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(dateText));
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: post some code so that we can identify what's the issue?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Sorry for that, updated.

Comment: Swedish is SE i think not SV. http://www.tuxx.nl/internationaal/landcodes/

Comment: I think here you can find language files 
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/js/locales

also have a look at this 
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/i18n.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have changed `language` from `en` to `sv` fine but you also need to include external `js` to support **swedish language** and you can get it here

**[Swedish JS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.sv.min.js)**

Now you just add `script src` to that `js` after adding `bootstrap-datepicker.js` as below

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.sv.min.js"></script>
```

**[Working DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bsw9odgo/)**

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)